# ios: NSMutableArray Count Prints Zero after adding object?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

My project is based on parsing xml data and adding it to array and display in respectives views,now my problem is am parsing xml and adding those objects it to nsmutablearray as shown below:

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    samplearray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    xmlParserObject = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:webData];
    [xmlParserObject setDelegate:self];
    [xmlParserObject parse];
     for (int i =0; i<[rssOutputData count]; i++) {
        NewsList *log = [rssOutputData objectAtIndex:i];
        feedid = log.id;
        NSLog(@"%d",feedid);
        Invit = log.newsletterdet;
        NSLog(@"%@",Invit);
         [samplearray addObject:log];
         NSLog(@"Count Final %d",[self.samplearray count]);

    }
    [[self navigationController] tabBarItem].badgeValue = mycount2;
    NSLog(@"%@",mycount2);
    [tblView reloadData];
    [connection release];

 }
```

The Above prints Count Value as `2014-04-04 15:21:10.009 cftsversion1[3087:70b] Count Final 1`

But when I call those Count in tableview methods, it  prints `0` so I cannot load datas in tableview Here is the code I tried for tableview methods:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 2;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0)
        return [samplearray count];Prints 0 here
    NSLog(@"Count %d",[samplearray count]); Prints 0 here
    if (section == 1)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"eventCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    for (UIView *view in cell.contentView.subviews) {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
    if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        NewsList *msglist = [samplearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = msglist.newsletterdet;
        NSLog(@"%@",msglist.newsletterdet);
        NSInteger stat = msglist.readflag;
        if ([[SingleTonClass sinlgeTon].colorArray2 containsObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row]] || stat ==  1) {
            cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
        }
        else{
            cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        }
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        }
    if (indexPath.section == 1)
    {
        UIButton *viewmoreButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        viewmoreButton.frame = CGRectMake(200.0f, 5.0f, 80.0f, 30.0f);
        [viewmoreButton setTitle:@"View More"  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell addSubview:viewmoreButton];
        [viewmoreButton addTarget:self
                           action:@selector(viewMore:)
                 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:viewmoreButton];

    }
    return cell;
    }
```

When run the above tableview code section 0 is not at all loading because array count prints 0 only section 1 is loading please help me how to solve this issue Thanks in advance

Comment: after addobject in your array fix retain your array like this [yourarray retain]; i think this is problem .

Comment: whats the attribute of the property for sample array? is it strong or weak?

Comment: @DarshanKunjadiya I tries this [samplearray retain]; but still problem remains same

Comment: please put this line of code in viewDidLoad samplearray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

Comment: try initializing array samplearray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; in viewDidLoad instead of connectionDidFinishLoading. It may work. If you are using ARC avoid retain & Release

Comment: S i added  samplearray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; in viewDidLoad still problem remains same

Comment: is SampleArray a property or instance variable??  how u synthesized that property ?? Is it weak one?? If weak then change to Strong!!

Comment: do not add.. remove the line from the connectionDidFinishLoading and put in ViewDidiLoad...... and check whether did you alloc the array any where.. please comment that line.... in that view where you are parsing... only 1 time alloc should be there

Comment: DILi its a property i declared like this @property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *samplearray; and synthesizing it

Comment: @babul if i remove this line from [samplearray addObject:log]; how it will work in viewdidload i didnt get u

Comment: i mean do not add this line "samplearray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];"

Comment: Ok. Intialize self.samplearray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init] in viewDidLoad. Make sure that you  are not initialzing it anywhere else.   Use "self.samplearray" instead of samplearray everywhere.

Comment: ya i added it and checked too but still not working

Comment: yes do as DILi said... use self.samplearray

Comment: @DILi i allocated samplearray as self.samplearray everywhere still it prints 0 at tableview methods "NOTE: it prints value at didfinishloading"

Comment: put your whole .h and .m code in http://pastie.org/ .... some minor mistake is there...

Comment: @Babul i posted there here is the link http://pastie.org/8993822

Comment: Bro i hope you are not deleting elements from  self.samplearray anywhere else. Also check if [tblView reloadData] is working properly. Initialy table will be loaded before completion  of connectionDidFinishLoading, so there count will be 0. Only in reload the count increments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intialize sampleArray in ViewDidLoad

`samplearray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]`

Make sure [tblView reloadData] is working properly.Initialy table will be loaded before completion of connectionDidFinishLoading, so count will be 0. Only in reload the count increments.

Answer (score 0):

I have doubt you are printing value in wrong way. Try to print it correctly first and update us:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0)
    {
       NSLog(@"Count %d",[samplearray count]);\\ Prints 0 here    
       return [samplearray count];\\Prints 0 here
    } 
    else if (section == 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and declare your NSMutableArray in `.h` file like:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *samplearray;
```